# regex masked characters in string

Tags: regex, string, replace, str-replace

It may be asked already but I need regex pattern for mask replacement below (n characters before the end with length of m)

```
n=3
m=4
In1Ex:ABCDEFG12345678 -> Out1Ex: ABCDEFG1****678
In2Ex:GFEDCBA876453 -> Out2Ex: GFEDCB****453


n=6
m=2
In3Ex:ABCDEFG12345678910 -> Out3Ex: ABCDEFG123**678910
In4Ex:GFEDCBA87645321 -> Out4Ex: GFEDCBA8**45321
```

Comment: What language? That will be crucial to give a complete answer.

Comment: See my answer, just saw your C# preference after writing something in JS.  Let me know if you really need a C#/JS example, but all you really need to do is make my regular expression dynamic based on `n` and `m`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [this](http://regex101.com/r/pW8wR1) [expression](http://regex101.com/r/xY8vE1) will get you started:

```
.{4}(?=.{3}$)
.{2}(?=.{6}$)
```

This matches any 4 (2) characters followed by the last 3 (6) characters.  Depending on the language, you can replace based on dynamic lengths.  In PHP:

```
$n = 3;
$m = 4;

$string = 'ABCDEFG12345678';
echo preg_replace('/.{' . $m . '}(?=.{' . $n . '}$)/', str_repeat('*', $m), $string);
// ABCDEFG1****678
```

More in depth RegExp explanation:

```
.{4}         # matches any 4 characters
(?=          # start a "lookahead"
  .{3}       # matches any 3 characters
  $          # matches the end of the string
)            # end the "lookahead"
```

This means that you will find whatever 4 characters are followed by 3 characters and the end of the string.  Lookaheads aren't returned as a match, so you will still just be replacing those 4 characters matched.